# Firebase support for push notifications on OSX

Tags: macos, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, osx-yosemite

I was using pod 'FirebaseOSX', '>=2.4.1' to install firebase to OSX. But I am not sure how to install firebase messaging option to pods. Could someone help?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: No. I had to use Apple push for MAC and it worked.

Comment: I did the same. Thanks